# In a For Loop, how to unpack "enumerate" and another iterable to three varaibles

Tags: python, python-3.x

The normal behavior is:

```
>>> for i,j in enumerate(['a','b','c']):
...   print ('i:', i,'j:', j)
...
i: 0 j: a
i: 1 j: b
i: 2 j: c
```

I want use this code, with extra list to unpack:

```
>>> for i,j,k in enumerate(['a','b','c']), ['d','e','f']:
...   print ('i:', i,'j:', j,'k:',k)
...
i: (0, 'a') j: (1, 'b') k: (2, 'c')
i: d j: e k: f
```

But the behavior I am expecting is:

```
>>> for i,j,k in enumerate(['a','b','c']), ['d','e','f']:
...   print ('i:', i,'j:', j,'k:',k)
...
i: 0 j: a k: d
i: 1 j: b k: e
i: 2 j: c k: f
```

why enumerate wasn't unpacked to i,j, while k holds the unpacked values of last list?

Comment: You're iterating over this 2-element tuple: `(enumerate(['a','b','c']), ['d','e','f'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
enumerate(['a','b','c']), ['d','e','f']
```

is a tuple of two elements : the enumerate object, and the `['d','e','f']` list. (Note that the comma `,` makes the tuple, not the parentheses)

When you iterate on it, you get on the first loop the enumerate object, which contains 3 items that get unpacked to `i`, `j` and `k`. On the second loop, you get the list, that gets similarly unpacked.

You want to iterate simultaneously on both, so use `zip`. You'll get on each loop a tuple from `enumerate`, and an integer from the list, so you have to reproduce that structure when unpacking:

```
for (i, j), k in zip(enumerate(['a','b','c']), ['d','e','f']):
    print ('i:', i,'j:', j,'k:',k)
```

But it might be clearer to zip the lists and enumerate the zipped lists:

```
for i, (j, k) in enumerate(zip(['a','b','c'], ['d','e','f'])):
    print ('i:', i,'j:', j,'k:',k)
```

Both give the same output:

```
i: 0 j: a k: d
i: 1 j: b k: e
i: 2 j: c k: f
```

Comment: Thanks!! Learned a new concept and a tip.